# Spring Boot 1.5.3 -- IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, maven

After deploying my project in IDE, all ok. But when I make 'package' at Maven, and tried to execute 'war' archive at the console, I get this exception:

> Unable to open nested entry
>   'WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar'. It has been compressed
>   and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check
>   the mechanism used to create your executable jar file

At Spring Boot 1.5.2 was all good.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `spring-aspects-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar` that inside `WEB-INF/lib/` is not extracted after compilation and your application can't extract classes from `*.jar` when you executing app.

Use maven dependencies instead direct `*.jar` files or specified plugin that will extract classes from `*.jar`'s and add them to your app.

If you can't find public repository that provide required dependencies then use [this instruction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to add your external JAR files into your local maven repository. Then just add such dependency and build app again.